# Swich JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Intento hacer un reloj con JavaScript que se actulice cada segundo marcando la hora actual, además ha de imprimir ciertos mensajes dependiendo de la franja horaria.

El problema es el swich que he implementado para verificar en la franja horaria que se encuentra no funciona de una manera adecuada, mostrando siempre el default.

Adjunto el código a continuación:

```js
let clock = setInterval(function () {

    let date = new Date();
        
    let hour = date.getHours();
    let minutes= date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    
    if (hour<10){hour = "0" + hour};
    if (minutes<10){minutes = "0" + minutes};
    if (seconds<10){seconds = "0" + seconds};

    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = "Son las " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    switch (hour) {
        
        case ((hour >= 4) && (hour >= 12)):
            document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "Buenos días";
          break;
        case ((hour >= 12) && (hour <= 15)):
            document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "Mediodía";
          break;
        case ((hour >= 18) && (hour <= 22)):
            document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "Hora de cenar";
          break;
        default:
            document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "A currar";
          break;
      }
    
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="clock"></div>
    <div id="variableArea"></div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el swich me compare de forma adecuada el valor? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer también con un sencillo:

`switch (true)` que evaluaría lo que haya ocurrido dentro de los `case`, por ejemplo:

```js
let clock = setInterval(function () {

    let date = new Date();
    let hour = date.getHours();
    let minutes= date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    if (hour<10){hour = "0" + hour};
    if (minutes<10){minutes = "0" + minutes};
    if (seconds<10){seconds = "0" + seconds};
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = "Son las " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    var txt="";
    switch (true) {
        
        case ((hour >= 4) && (hour <= 12)):
            txt="Buenos días";
          break;
        case ((hour >= 12) && (hour <= 15)):
            txt = "Mediodía";
          break;
        case ((hour >= 18) && (hour <= 22)):
            txt = "Hora de cenar";
          break;
        default:
            txt = "A currar";
          break;
      }
      document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = txt;    
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="clock"></div>
    <div id="variableArea"></div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los rangos no son válidos en JavaScript, cuando hay situaciones así, puedes desarrollar todos los casos de la siguiente manera:

```js
let clock = setInterval(function () {

    let date = new Date();
        
    let hour = date.getHours();
    let minutes= date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    
    if (hour<10){hour = "0" + hour};
    if (minutes<10){minutes = "0" + minutes};
    if (seconds<10){seconds = "0" + seconds};

    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = "Son las " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    switch (hour) {

    case 4:
    case 5: 
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:                
        document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "Buenos días";
        break;
    case 12:
    case 13:
    case 14:
    case 15:                
        document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "Mediodía";
        break;
    case 18:
    case 19:
    case 20:
    case 21:
    case 22:                
        document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "Hora de cenar";
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById('variableArea').innerHTML = "A currar";
        break;
}
    
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="clock"></div>
    <div id="variableArea"></div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

Los 3 Ifs que tienes donde le agregas un 0 a la izquierda del valor me parece que no deberían ir, salvo tengas que presentar un formato al cliente.

Comment: Muchísicas gracias. ¿Cómo podría imprimir dentro de un mismo case varias cosas?

Comment: Vale, con cariño hermano/a, ¿a qué te refieres?